# Unity How to combine each object name?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I put several button and i linked onClick() each buttons.
It's okay to print each button name.

But when i click another button, The text didn't combine previous text...

========================================================

```
public Text showText; //print text

public int count = 0; // count how many times click button


public void ButtonClick_1()
{
    Debug.Log("Button Clicked!");

    print(gameObject.name);

    if (count == 0) { showText.text = gameObject.name; }
    else { showText.text += gameObject.name; }
    count++;


}
```

==================================================

First 
click button1 => it's okay to print " button1 "

Second
click button1 again => It's okay to print " button1button1"

Third
click button2 => It's not okay to print. print like "button2". I hope it print"button1button1button2"

==========================================================

I want to figure out this.....

I have to put several buttons so use tag is more useful? 
I'm not used to use tag. Hope someone help me out.

Comment: Could you post your complete code?

Comment: Umm.. That's all.... rest of the codes are void start() and void update()..

Comment: Well if there is a `ButtonClick_1` I'ld assume there is also `ButtonClick_2` etc? Or do you have the same script on multiple different buttons? In this case it would be quite obvious that `count` is initially `0` for all of them ;) you could make `private static int count;` so it is shared between all instances or simply not overwrite but always use `showText.text += ...` instead

Comment: I have same script on multiple buttons. I really appreciate it. I fixed it and it worked!!! Thank you so much:)

Comment: just use a static field to store the text.  then assign it

Comment: private static string firstnum;
 firstnum = gameObject.name; you mean like this? Actually i print like "000" ,"001",,"012","123".... showText.text = "0" + firstnum + gameObject.name; Is it right?

Comment: So you only want the 3 last pressed  buttons?

Comment: Yes. like number keypad.. There are 10 buttons. If i pressed two, zero, nine. print 209. If i pressed another button again. It's not allowed to print out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I understood you have this script on multiple buttons.

You have a check on `count` which initially is `0` for each individual instance.

So instead you could make it [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) so it is "shared" between all instances or better said makes it a static class member which is not related to any instance.

```
public Text showText;

public static int count = 0;

public void ButtonClick_1()
{
    Debug.Log("Button Clicked!");

    print(gameObject.name);

    if (count == 0) 
    {
        showText.text = gameObject.name;
    }
    else 
    {
        showText.text += gameObject.name; 
    }
    count++;
}
```

So that the text is only overwritten by the very first button click.

---

Your comment

> Actually i print like "000" ,"001",,"012","123".

sounds like you actually want to print always the last three buttons.

I would rather use e.g. a `static List<string>` like

```
private static List<string> lastThreeButtons = new List<string>();

public void ButtonClick()
{
    lastThreeButtons.Add(name);

    if(lastThreeButtons.Count == 3)
    {
        showText.text = lastThreeButtons[0] + lastThreeButtons[1] + lastThreeButtons[3];

        lastThreeButtons.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it :

Have a singleton class :

```
public class TextManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static TextManager Instance;

    public UnityEngine.UI.Text myUIText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public void AddLine(string _line)
    {
        myUIText.text += $"{_line} \n";
    }
}
```

Put this Component on a GameObject and **link the UIText in the inspector**

Then on my ButtonScript I would have this :

```
public void ButtonClick()
{
    Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name} Clicked!");
    TextManager.Instance.AddLine(gameObject.name);
}
```